# Could not find image React Native

Tags: xcode, react-native

### Apple M1 Chip

### React Native Version

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.63.4
```

## Xcode Version

```
Version 13.2.1 (13C100)
```

### Error

> [native] Could not find image
> file:///Users/infotech/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A71B37C9-860C-4BCC-B0C6-72450CB35111/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C79835EC-D07E-47CD-B007-649CD8C1AF52/MyApp.app/assets/Assets/Images/splash.jpg

Image proper show in debug mode, but when I try to release mode

The problem is when I try to find an image from the path then the `assets` folder does not show.

but when

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?